# Difference between ClearSelection() and Clear() in .net

Tags: c#, .net

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

What is the difference between

```
DDL.ClearSelection()
```

and

```
DDL.Items.Clear()
```

Thanks

Comment: Please read the documentation for this: [`DropDownList.ClearSelection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.clearselection.aspx) vs [`ItemCollection.Clear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.clear.aspx) (from [`ListControl.Items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ClearSelection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.clearselection(v=vs.110).aspx) unselects any *selected* item. You might use this, for instance, after you've taken action on the user's selection. The available selections are left, but none of the items are selected.

[`Items.Clear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) removes everything from the `Items` *collection*. You'd use this to rebuild the list of available items for the user to select. It'd make little sense to use this without rebuilding the `Items` (either manually or through data-binding) as you'd be left with an empty dropdown. This would also, in effect, clear the user's selection (since the item they selected will be removed).